# Trying to use LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder into a Dataset with Multiple Columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to convert multiple columns which there are a bunch of data in categorical values; but i getting a error when i goes to use OneHotEncoder

[My Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slWZg.png)

**1) Separating the columns in X_census and Y_census** (X_census contains categorical values):

```
X_census  = df[['workclass',
               'education',
               'marital-status',
               'occupation',
               'relationship',
               'race',
               'sex',
               'native-country']]

Y_census = df['income']
```

**2) Treating categorical values from X_census with LabelEncoder**:

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

```
le = LabelEncoder()
X_1 = X_census.apply(le.fit_transform)
X_2 = X_1.to_numpy()
```

**3) Now using OneHotEncoder into my X_2 to convert categorical to numerical values**:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

oh = OneHotEncoder()
onehotencoder_census = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('OneHot', oh, X_2[:])],remainder='passthrough')
X_census = onehotencoder_census.fit_transform(X_census) # Error appears here!
```

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDi6O.png)

Comment: Can you show your X_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### you can use pandas.get_dummies

> > df = pd.DataFrame({"marital_status":['S','M','D','S','M','D','S','M','D'],
> > "sex":["male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male"],
> > "education":['grad','post-grad','grad','post-grad','grad','post-grad','grad','post-grad','grad'],
> > "income":[125,135,120,110,90,150,180,130,110]})

[image]

> > pd.get_dummies(df)

[image]